# Cut K sequences of length L to obtain the biggest number

Tags: string, algorithm, numbers

We have a number of N digits (it can start with 0). We must find the biggest number which can be obtained cutting K disjoint sequences of length L.
N can be very big so our number should be stored as a string.

Example 1)

```
nr = 12122212212212121222
K = 2, L = 3
answer: 22212212221222
We can cut "121" (from 0th digit) and "121" (from 12th digit).
```

Example 2)

```
nr = 0739276145
K = 3, L = 3
answer: 9
We can cut "073", "276" and "145".
```

I have tried something like this:

```
void cut(string str, int K, int L) {
    if (K == 0)
        return;

    // here we cut a single sequence of length L
    // in a way that the new number is the biggest

    cut(str, K - 1, L);
}
```

But in this way, I can cut 2 sequences which in the initial number are not disjoint, so my method it's not correct. Please help me solve the problem!

Comment: How is `22212212221222` 2 sequences of length 3? How is `9` 3 sequences of length 3? The question is very unclear, and your attempted code doesn't help -- how is the result computed and returned?

Comment: I thought is very clear that you have to cut K sequences of length L from the initial number to obtain another number (and this one must be maximum). I have updated the examples.
The initial number, K, and L are given and you have to find the number obtained after the cuts.

Comment: I see now -- you're removing sections rather than taking them. The problem seems to have a straightforward recurrence defining the optimal solution: `cut(s, K, L) = max(s[:i] + cut(s[i+L:], K-1, L) for i = 0... len(S)-K*L)` with the base case `cut(s, 0, L) = s`. And you can solve those equations efficiently with dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `cuts`recursively:

```
cuts(s, 0, L) = s
cuts(s, K, L) = max(s[i:j] + cuts(s[j+L:], K-1, L) for j=i..len(s)-K*L)
```

As is normal in these problems, you can use dynamic programming to avoid an exponential runtime. You can probably avoid so much string slicing and appending, but this is an example solution in Python:

```
def cuts(s, K, L):
    dp = [s[i:] for i in xrange(len(s)+1)]
    for k in xrange(1, K+1):
        dp = [max(s[i:j] + dp[j+L] for j in xrange(i, len(dp)-L))
              for i in xrange(len(dp)-L)]
    return dp[0]

print cuts('12122212212212121222', 2, 3)
print cuts('0739276145', 3, 3)
```

Output:

```
22212212221222
9
```